# How to build a TensorFlow graph with NN layers in a for loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The TF tutorial I'm using builds the graph for forward propagation in the following way:

```
Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1, X), b1)
A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)
Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2, A1), b2)
A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)
Z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W3, A2), b3)
```

I'm trying to build basically the same thing, but not with a fixed set of layers.  My initial intent was to adapt the structure of my hand-coded python version of the NN. I start by initializing the parameters (in a function):

```
def initialize_parameters_deep(self, layer_dims):
    """
    Arguments:
    layer_dims -- python array (list) containing the dimensions of each layer in the network

    Returns:
    parameters -- python dictionary containing the parameters (as tensors) "W1", "b1", ..., "WL", "bL":
                    Wl -- weight matrix of shape (layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l-1])
                    bl -- bias vector of shape (layer_dims[l], 1)
    """

    parameters = {}
    L = len(layer_dims)            # number of layers in the network

    for l in range(1, L):
        parameters['W' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable('W' + str(l), [layer_dims[l], layer_dims[l-1]], initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        parameters['b' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable('b' + str(l), [layer_dims[l], 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

    return parameters
```

With that as my parameters, I want to do forward propagation this way:

```
def forward_propagation(self, X, parameters):
    """
    Implement forward propagation for the [LINEAR->RELU]*(L-1)->LINEAR->SOFTMAX computation

    Arguments:
    X -- data, tensor with shape (input size, number of examples)
    parameters -- output of initialize_parameters_deep()

    Returns:
    AL -- last post-activation value
    """

    A = X
    L = len(parameters) // 2                  # number of layers in the neural network
    for l in range(1, L):
        A_prev = A 
        Z = tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters["W" + str(l)], A_prev), parameters["b" + str(l)])
        A = tf.nn.relu(Z)

    Z = tf.add(tf.matmul(parameters["W" + str(L), A), parameters["b" + str(L)])
    AL = tf.nn.softmax(Z)

    return AL, caches
```

But I feel like there's no way for TF to evaluate that python for loop. Is there a way to do this with a loop that TF can effectively build into the graph?

Comment: What do you mean "there's no way"? This is the easiest way to define a network with many layers.

Comment: @xdurch0 So you're saying this will work within TensorFlow?

Comment: @xdurch0 Also, I agree that this is the easiest way to define a network in pure Python/NumPy. It's what I'm already using with my hand-coded network. I'm trying to port it over to TensorFlow.

Comment: Yes, this should work. Why don't you try it?

Comment: @xdurch0 I think I will. Thanks for the input! :-)